# Script request not being sent with Authentication header

Tags: html, http, basic-authentication, es6-modules

I have a page which has basic authentication on it.  Once I've authenticated my requests for the page and it's resources (CSS etc) have the Authentication header

```
Authorization   Basic NOTREALNOTREALNOTREALNOTREALNOTREAL=
```

At the end of the body I am loading an external script.

```
<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
```

This request is not being sent with the Authentication header. It is the only thing on the page which isn't. This causes a 401 repsonse with the following header

```
WWW-Authenticate    Basic realm="mydomain.com"
```

This happens in both chrome and firefox.

Does anyone know why this is the case or how to get it to be sent?

Comment: Simple answer is to allow un-authorized access to the asset. Does it really need to be hidden from www?

Comment: @Christo I _could_ do that, but I'm mostly interested in understanding why this is happening.

Comment: I've noticed the exact same thing. My <script type="module"> loads are not having the Auth header sent, in either Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like this is a quirk of `<script type="module">`](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2557), that causes them all to be treated as CORS requests, and thus they don't send Authentication headers by default.

This can be worked around by adding the `crossorigin="use-credentials"` attribute to your script tag:

```html
<script type="module" src="/main.js" crossorigin="use-credentials"></script>
```

should work.

Comment: Finally got round to testing this and it works with the cross-origin attribute.